# Writing 8 bit values to a binary file in python v3.3

Tags: python, binaryfiles

Please let me know the best way to write 8bit values to a file in python.  The values can be between 0 and 255.
I open the file as follows:

```
f = open('temp', 'wb')
```

Assume the value I am writing is an int between 0 and 255 assigned to a variable, e.g.

```
x = 13
```

This does not work:

```
f.write(x)
```

..as you experts know does not work.  python complains about not being able to write ints to buffer interface.  As a work around I am writing it as a hex digit.  Thus:

```
f.write(hex(x))
```

..and that works but is not only space inefficient but clearly not the right python way.  Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly creating a `bytes` object:

```
f.write(bytes([x]))
```

You can also output a series of bytes as follows:

```
f.write(bytes([65, 66, 67]))
```

Comment: Many thanks Jim! I really appreciate the example.  Much more helpful this way.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/struct.html) module...

```
import struct
x = 13
with open('temp', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack('>I', x))  # Big-endian, unsigned int
```

To read x from the file...

```
with open('temp', 'rb') as f:
    x, = struct.unpack(">I", f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write an item of `bytes` data type, not integer.